# oracle filter rows depending on few values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data of the below format and need help in filtering the output. tried multiple combinations but couldn't get through

the data I have is

```
User Id   Comments               Status   Date        Set#
123       First Edit              E        22-Feb-17   0
123       First Edit              E        22-Feb-17   55
123       First Edit              X        22-Feb-17   55
123       First Edit              X        22-Feb-17   55
123       Second Edit             X        22-Feb-17   55
123       Second Edit             X        22-Feb-17   55
```

if the text between two rows is same I should select first occurrence of that row and if the text is different I have to select both.

The output should look like

```
User Id   Comments               Status   Date        Set#
123       First Edit              E        22-Feb-17   0
123       Second Edit             X        22-Feb-17   55
```

Comment: what makes you pick the row with Status = 'E' and Set# = 0 for the comments = 'First Edit', rather than say Status = 'X' and Set# = 55? (Bearing in mind that heap tables don't have any particular order to them, so saying "because it's the first row listed" means nothing, unless you are ordering the results on specific columns)

Comment: use `rank() OVER ( [ query_partition_clause] ORDER BY clause ) ` with your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userId, comments order by date) as sequm
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  You say "select first occurrence of that row".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no *first* occurrence.  This answer assumes that `date` actually has a time component that specifies the ordering you intend.

Comment: yes the date value shown above is a `timestamp` column and it makes perfect sense to do a rank and then take the 1st rank